# presence of cout changing the result of the program

Tags: c++, cout

I am writing a program which sums the first ten digits of one-hundred 50 digit numbers which are in a text file. Easy enough, and I got the right answer, but I'm trying to understand some weird things that appear to be going on. When the first cout line is included as it appears below the program outputs:

```
8549904804355727945614717320-7-60-4-3-2-7-3-4-8-7-7-6-1-840-9-5-2-3-39622981389563771795892386478402037366780930326737553
```

When it is changed to the comment on the right of it, it outputs:

```
97414719961102146325906539660-4-7-2-4-4-3-4-8-2-8-3-8-2-870-8-5-2-3-39622981389563771795892386478402037366780930326737553
```

I'm having trouble understanding
1) how what I output could somehow affect the future values it output.
2) How the dashes get into the program.

Note: the output is the sum of all the strings in reverse.

```
char file[] = "nums.txt";
ifstream ss(file);
string iString;
string sarr[100];
int sum[100];

while(getline(ss, iString, '\n')) {
  sarr[i] = iString;
  i++;
}
ss.close();

cout << sarr[0] << endl << endl; //or cout<<(int)sarr[0][3]-48<<endl<<endl;
for(int i = 99; i >= 0; i--) {
  sum[i] = 0;
  for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    sum[i] += (int)sarr[j][i];
  }
  sum[i] -= 4800;//since 100 strings and '0' in ascii is 48 subtract 48*100
}

for(int i = 99; i > 0; i--) {
  sum[i-1] += sum[i] / 10;
  sum[i] = sum[i] % 10;
  cout << sum[i];
}
cout << sum[0] << endl << endl;
```

Comment: Which cout line are you changing to be a comment? There are three of them.

Comment: what are you trying to do with this sarr[0][3]- 48...some comments would make your program more readable

Comment: There's a couple of `endl`s between the first and second cout. Did you omit the first line of output or mash the two lines together?

Comment: And, can you show a few example lines from the input file?

Comment: @Sancho The first line in the input file which is sarr[0] is: 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
The second line is: 46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
Also I intended the two endl just to make it easier to read when it outputs so I have the extra line of whitespace.

Comment: @SumitJain sarr[0][3] is the char '0' if you look at my above comment so I was just testing whether it actually outputs the int 0 the way it should. Then I came across the bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You say the first line of your text file is `37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250`, which is 50 characters long, but here

```
for(int i = 99; i >= 0; i--) {
  sum[i] = 0;
  for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    sum[i] += (int)sarr[j][i];
  }
  sum[i] -= 4800;//since 100 strings and '0' in ascii is 48 subtract 48*100
}
```

You are looping with `i` going from 99 to 0 and using `i` to index that string. Your indices are going out of bounds and causing undefined behaviour. This is the danger of using hardcoded values instead of using the data to determine the bounds of the loop.

When random things like this happen and you're doing a lot of work with arrays, the first thing you should look for is indexing out of bounds somewhere. That is probably the most frequent cause of UB.

Comment: wow incredible thank you. So now that I know its such a stupid bug should I delete this post or leave it up in the off-chance someone else will find it useful?

Comment: @emschorsch I would leave it up, it's a perfectly valid question. Besides, it may remind someone in the future to "check again" for going out of bounds.